# How to calculate number of items on the basis table td?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using this code for calculating number of times a vehicle is added. The code is not returning the correct value. I want to calculate how many times the same vehicle is selected in each row of the table.

```js
function calculateNumberOfVehicles(vehicleId) {
  var returnValue = 0;
  var table = $("#selected_students");
  table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {

    var counter = 0;
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    var actualId = rowId.substr(rowId.indexOf("_") + 1).trim();
    var addedVehicleId = $("#lockedVehicleId_" + actualId).text();
    if (parseInt(vehicleId) == parseInt(addedVehicleId)) {
      counter++
      returnValue = counter;
    }
  });
  return returnValue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="selected_students">
    <tr id="row_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc">
      <td>Adam Zaffar</td>
      <td>L.K.G</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td id="lockedRoute_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc">Karan Nagar</td>
      <td id="lockedStop_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc">Lal chowk</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicle_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc">JK 123</td>
      <td class="delete_row_dynamic"><button relation="5b962874d2ccda10ac003702" title="Delete" id="5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" class="btn btn-danger table_btn btn-outline btn-sm deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
      <td id="lockedRouteId_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" class="hide">5b83dc30d2ccda0b60005c0f</td>
      <td id="lockedStopId_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" class="hide">b930e948-202b-697c-5615-58939cff2ac2</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicleId_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" class="hide">5b962874d2ccda10ac003702</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicleIdSeats_5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" class="hide">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c">
      <td>Adnan Mir</td>
      <td>L.K.G</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td id="lockedRoute_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c">New Jersey City</td>
      <td id="lockedStop_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c">City Center</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicle_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c">JK 123</td>
      <td class="delete_row_dynamic"><button relation="5b962874d2ccda10ac003702" title="Delete" id="5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c" class="btn btn-danger table_btn btn-outline btn-sm deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
      <td id="lockedRouteId_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c" class="hide">5b7fb426d2ccda11fc005185</td>
      <td id="lockedStopId_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c" class="hide">aa61d076-30c1-31ff-c245-968178042e46</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicleId_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c" class="hide">5b962874d2ccda10ac003702</td>
      <td id="lockedVehicleIdSeats_5b17cc27bb2c5633f400197c" class="hide">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please specify your question

Comment: if   calculateNumberOfVehicles("5b962874d2ccda10ac003702") is called then the output should be 2 because there are two rows where lockedVehicleId_.... is "5b962874d2ccda10ac003702"

Comment: why parseInt is used, when comparing values for vehicleId & addedVehicleId, when both values are actually string containing letters. After using parseInt on such variable values, incorrect value is getting returned.

Comment: u r right sir... but i have removed it but it is still not giving the desired output

Comment: Is there any other method to get the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = calculateNumberOfVehicles('5b962874d2ccda10ac003702');
console.log(result); // This will output the number in console.
function calculateNumberOfVehicles(vehicleId) {
  var returnValue = 0;
  var table = $("#selected_students");
  var counter = 0;
  table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    var actualId = rowId.substr(rowId.indexOf("_") + 1).trim();
    var addedVehicleId = $("#lockedVehicleId_" + actualId).text();
    if (parseInt(vehicleId) == parseInt(addedVehicleId)) {
      counter++
      returnValue = counter;
    }
  });
  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateNumberOfVehicles(vehicleId) {
    var returnValue = 0;
    var table = $("#selected_students");
    table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
        var actualId = rowId.substr(rowId.indexOf("_") + 1).trim();
        var addedVehicleId = $("#lockedVehicleId_" + actualId).text();
        if (parseInt(vehicleId) == parseInt(addedVehicleId)) {
            returnValue++;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```